# How to run Jenkins job by a specific user

Tags: jenkins

I want to run Jenkins job as a specific user, not the logged in user that is running the job.

I have setup SSH Agent for that user, created separate Credentials and select those when I configure job, yet Jenkins still running under logged in user.

It copies the git repository under logged in user home directory on Jenkins slave and not that specific user.

Any Idea?